# Keystrokes to text converter method? (from an audio file, from previously recorded sounds of keystrokes)

Tags: audit, keyloggers

I have an e.g.: WAV file that contains the sounds of a man typing on his keyboard (English or any language)

How can I convert this WAV file to a TXT file? I mean are there any scripts/programs that can convert it? (Using e.g.: statistical methods, like "e" is often used in e.g.: English, etc.)
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called "Keyboard Acoustic Emanations" and I don't think there is anything available publicly as a tool.

There has been research on the subject, the most notable being this: http://berkeley.edu/news/media/releases/2005/09/14_key.shtml  (paper: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~zl/papers/keyboard-ccs05.pdf presentation: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~zl/ppt/keyboard-ccs05.ppt )

There is one real program I'm aware of that can translate from sounds of typing to text, but it works if the user types in Morse Code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find a link to some of the details that came out about cold war analysis in this area - humans rather than computers carrying out the analysis, obviously, but the broad issue was the learning curve to identify keys, as it not only depended on the sound of the key being pressed, but on the person typing (as that affected timing between keystrokes)